# Should I create a new branch for another "test" implementation?

Tags: git, branch

Help a junior dev with 4 months experience...

I have this branch: `feature/return-email-list`

**Context**: I have finished a new feature on `feature/return-email-list` where it's done, tested and working well. But today, at the time I was opening a pull request, a slightly different implementation idea came up.

**My question is:** As this new idea is very similar to the implementation I did, what would be the best option? Should I start a new branch from the branch `feature/return-email-list`, something like `feature/return-email-list-2` or just make the changes and, if it's not succeed, rollback to the last commit?

Answer (score 1):

Start a new branch. You want to *keep* the work you already did on the first implemenation, so that it's easier to compare it to your new implementation. In the end, you'll pick one branch to merge via pull request, and leave the other for future reference ("we tried this but decided not to use it because ...") (or delete it).

The question is, what you should branch *from*? The same commit that `feature/return-email-list` branched from, or `feature/return-email-list` itself, or some commit in between? That depends on how much overlap your new implemenation has with the existing one.